Is `Intl` object still expensive to create?
Several years ago, I read somewhere in MDN that creating Intl object like NumberFormat is expensive, and we should only create one then reuse. One benchmark in 2014 also agrees.
However, I can't find that recommendation anymore in MDN for Intl. Is it still true? Or the creating of such object is so fast now we no longer need reusing?

This depends on how you're using it. Creating any object in a loop - as in that benchmark - will be slower than creating one instance and re-using it. If you just need a single instance, then this is a non-issue. If you can provide details of your specific use case then we can offer more relevant assistance.

Required reading: Which is faster?

Yes, in the past they involve loading locale data and setting up a configuration, so it made sense to create and reuse them.
But today, modern JavaScript engines (like V8 in Chrome, SpiderMonkey in Firefox, and JavaScriptCore in Safari) have optimized the creation of Intl objects. Today, creating a new Intl.NumberFormat object is much faster, and the overhead has been significantly reduced. These optimizations may have made the performance impact negligible in many real-world scenarios.
That said, while creating Intl objects is faster now, in high-performance applications or code that calls formatting functions in tight loops, it could still be a good practice to cache and reuse the Intl objects to avoid unnecessary creation. For most applications, though, the performance difference may no longer be significant.
